# trimming ps x to remove the path before the process name

Tags: awk, sed

I need to format the output of the command "ps x" in a specific way such that the pathname in front of the process is removed, perhaps using awk or sed.

for example: if the command "ps x" gives the output below:

```
$ps x 

21379 ?        S      0:00 /home/something/etc/processA
21381 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/something/bin/nameB -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7
```

I want the output as below :

```
21379 ? S  0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB  -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7
```

also, it would be good to know how to get:

```
21379 ? S  0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB
```

As of now, I do something that is pathlength dependent, and also I have to remove the grep process.

```
$ps x | grep -v grep | grep -e processA -e nameB | awk -F '[/]' {'print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5'} | awk {'print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$8'}
```

which gives

```
21379 ? S 0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB
```

For legacy code reasons I can not use "ps -e -o pid,tty,stat,time,comm".

Update 1) It would be good to have something that is pathlength independent.

Comment: I could not understand what is wrong, it seems to not work when there are no arguments to process. for your script, the output is                                         
'21379 ?        S      0:00 /home/something/etc/processA
21381 ?        Sl     0:00 nameB -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7' Check compared to output I need.

Comment: I have updated the comment

Comment: There was something that was not generic with the script you mentioned. it does not work when there was 'pts/15' instead of '?' you could check with below file content, replace <endline>: `$cat ps_x_file.txt <endline>

 4434 pts/15   S+     0:02 /home/something/etc/processA  

 4689 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/something/bin/nameB -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7`

Comment: replace '?' with 'pts/15' in your file, that should be sufficient

Comment: no, it does not work. you should be able to check it yourself now. I am very happy with jotne's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some to begin with:

```
ps x | awk '{n=split($5,a,"/");print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[n]}'
21379 ? S 0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB
```

```
ps x | awk '{n=split($5,a,"/");print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[n],$6,$7,$8}'
21379 ? S 0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7
```

```
ps x | awk '{n=split($5,a,"/");$5=a[n]}1'
21379 ? S 0:00 processA
21381 ? Sl 0:00 nameB -log /home/something/log/nameB/log.ttyS7 /dev/ttyS7
```

Comment: That looks good, is there any way to generalize $6,$7,$8 to instead "remaining columns/arguments"

Comment: @user49535 That is what is done in the last example.  Only field 5 is changed, rest are printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single awk script to achieve all tasks

```
awk '
   # Remove path from 5th argument
$5 ~ /\// { sub("^.*/", "", $5) ; }
    # Print only matching processes
$5 ~ "^(processA|nameB)$" { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }
```